# File is not defined in Python

Tags: python

How come when I try to call the function, it always says
"ttp_0_5" is not defined? The file I want to read out is in the same directory. I guess I have to define it anywhere, like in Java, but I do need help in this case.

```
import math

def readInstance(ttp_0_5):
    value_mode = False
    nodes = 0
    
    file = open(ttp_0_5)

    # Einlesen der Datei                 
    for line in file:
        # aufsplitten der gelesenen Zeile
        fields = line.strip().split()
        
        if not value_mode and not fields[0] == "#EOF":
            # Metadaten einlesen (N = Anzahl der Knoten)
            if fields[0] == "N":
                nodes = int(fields[2])
            # wenn "#NODES" gefunden wird, folgen die Knoten und Zuordnungen
            elif fields[0] == "#NODES":
                value_mode = True
                items = []
                edges = []
                
        # Werte-Lese-Modus und noch nicht end of file (EOF)
        elif not fields[0] == "#EOF":
            items.append(eval(fields[1]))
            if len(fields) > 2:
                edges.append(eval(fields[2]))
            else:
                edges.append([])
    
    # dict aufbauen
    graph = {}
    for i in range(len(items)):
        graph[i+1] = [] 
    
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if edges[i]:
            for j in edges[i]:
                if i != (j-1):
                    l = graph[i+1]
                    l.append((j,math.dist(items[i], items[j-1])))
                    graph[i+1] = l
                    
                else:
                    pass
        else:
            for j in range(nodes):
                if i != (j):
                    l = graph[i+1]
                    l.append((j+1,math.dist(items[i], items[j])))
                    graph[i+1] = l
                else:
                    pass    
    return graph 

readInstance(open(ttp_0_5))
```

Comment: `ttp_0_5` isn't defined

Comment: I voted to re-open as this error is reproducible and not caused by a typo, but rather by lack of understanding how variables, functions etc work

Comment: I assume you didn't write the `readInstance` function yourself because I think if you had you would know how to call it. Unfortunately the question has been closed so I can't post more help in an answer, but try to read some basic material to learn how Python programming works https://realpython.com/python-variables/ https://realpython.com/courses/defining-and-calling-functions/

Comment: Yeah i just have to use some Python Methods thats it

Answer (score 2):

You should call the function like this:

```py
readInstance("ttp_0_5")
```

as no `ttp_0_5` variable is not declared.

So, either declare ttp_0_5 = "ttp_0_5", or pass the string directly.

Comment: Thanks so far. And what do i pass in the Methodhead and when i declare "file"  ?

Comment: this answer will also give an error

Comment: @Anentropic why is that? The answer solves the error mentioned in the question!!

Comment: I don't think `readInstance` expects a file object as argument

Comment: @Anentropic right, I corrected. didn't check the function definition.

Comment: Yes it does expect a file. But no matter what i try its always:  'module' object has no attribute 'dist'

Comment: @NasiGorengAyam `math.dist` was added in Python 3.8, sounds like you must be using an older version https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.dist